# Messaging Stopped Ejabberd

Tags: service, messaging, ejabberd

I am using mod_Push module to send push notification.

After starting this module, my messaging service has stopped and as I stop this module, it starts working again. I customized the mod_push module and used user_send_packet hook so that I can send push notification for each and every message received at server.

Log is as follows giving crash in mod_mam

```
[error] <0.16149.0>@ejabberd_hooks:run_fold1:371 {function_clause,[{mod_mam,should_archive,[ok],[{file,"src/mod_mam.erl"},{line,3‌​08}]},{mod_mam,user_send_packet,4,[{file,"src/mod_mam.erl"},{}
```

Comment: You should look to your log files. I expect you will see a crash that will put you in the right direction.

Comment: log is as follows giving  crash in mod_mam                                                                                                                       [error] <0.16149.0>@ejabberd_hooks:run_fold1:371 {function_clause,[{mod_mam,should_archive,[ok],[{file,"src/mod_mam.erl"},{line,308}]},{mod_mam,user_send_packet,4,[{file,"src/mod_mam.erl"},{}

Comment: So, it seems the mod_push module need to be updated for compliance with ejabberd API. One of its hooks returns an incorrect value that is not accepted by archive module.

Comment: i am not getting messages but presence packet are transporting through .

Comment: Yes, that's what I said: mod_push is sending bad data through hooks to mod_mam, making it crash. It mean message is lost. presence are not archive so do not get through the same path. so I confirm that mod_push need to be updated to support ejabberd latest API.

Answer (score 0):

Your `mod_push` will need to be updated to support the latest version of ejabberd API. The log you provided shows that messages are lost because `mod_push` is crashing archiving module, probably by passing an incorrect return from an ejabberd API hook.

Comment: I made some changes and messages  transporting has started  but for my push  am getting this :  [error] <0.1857.1>@ejabberd_hooks:run_fold1:371 {undef,[{mod_push,create_message,[{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>},{<<"to">>

Comment: Well, it simply means that the function your are calling does not exist, at least with the signature you are using.

Comment: thanks mickael , where can i get the details of ejabberd sql  schema

Comment: Thanks Mickael , it was helpful and worked for me.can you help  me to know where i can get the details of sql schema , i mean all the tables and fields? specially i need user roster .

Comment: SQL schema is include in package and in source code: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/tree/master/sql